# header file <execution> missing in gcc 7.2 (Ubuntu) : how to solve it?

Tags: header-files, c++17, execution

few days ago I updated in my Ubuntu 16.04 Server Edition gcc to gcc 7.2 version:

```
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04)
```

which should be the most updated version of gcc available for Ubuntu

Now, compiling an example of a book,

```
g++ -std=c++17 auto_parallel.cpp -oauto_parallel

auto_parallel.cpp:5:10: fatal error: execution: No such file or directory
include <execution>

~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.
```

How to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance. Marco

Comment: I don't think GCC 7.2 supports execution policies.  `"most updated version" != "contains all C++ features"`

Comment: libstdc++ (the standard library GCC uses) does not implement the `<execution>` header yet. See also their [C++17 status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017), in the table under "The Parallelism TS Should be Standardized"

Answer (score 2):

update your GUN compiler to version9， according to(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support
and https://www.bojankomazec.com/2020/03/upgrading-gnu-cc-compilers-on-ubuntu.html)

`sudo apt install -y gcc-9 g++-9 -y`

and remap your compiler to gcc-9

`sudo rm /usr/bin/g++`

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-9 /usr/bin/g++`

`sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc`

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-9 /usr/bin/gcc`

Verify the compiler version

`ls -la /usr/bin/gcc`

`ls -la /usr/bin/g++`